# Why is it customary to bow at certain points when saying kaddish?

Tags: kaddish, bowing-kneeling

It is [customary](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/371110/jewish/Text-of-the-Mourners-Kaddish.htm) to bow at certain points when saying kaddish. The link is to a chabad site and I have seen bowing in other communities as well. At first sight (excuse pun) it  appears to be a visual cue for the response.

Why is it done?

What is the source?

Comment: Shulhan Aruch Siman 56, Shut Ish Masliah vol. 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sefer HaKadish page 213 note 2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8837&st=&pgnum=225) brings in the name of the Pardes HaGodol in the name of the Rokeach that we bow 4 times in Kadish in connection with the 4 names in [Malachi 1:11](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14261&st=&pgnum=403) (3 times Shemi and once Hashem Tzevakos)

Comment: You have an answer to [this](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/49038/4794) question if you want to write it up.

Answer (score 0):

The earliest source I can find is the Tur (end of 56) who mentions that "Rav Nachshon wrote that there are 4 obligatory bowings, and one optional."

He then continues with an explanation for the 5 - corresponding to 5 names of Hashem... but since I don't understand what he wrote, I cannot transcripe it.

Comment: Did you check the Beit Yosef there? He usually quotes earlier sources surrounding the Tur's rulings.