# Should the Chazan bow when reciting Kaddish (even before "Oseh Shalom...")? If so, when?

Tags: tefilla, chazzan-prayer-leader, kaddish, bowing-kneeling

The Chazan bows 3 times when reciting "Oseh Shalom..."

At the beginning of Kaddish should he bow as well? And if so, when?

Occasionally I've seen a Chazan or two bow, but the vast majority don't.

Comment: I was taught to bow at yitgadal, yitbarach and titkabeil (if applicable) but I was 13 at the time so no sources.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15739/why-is-it-customary-to-bow-at-certain-points-when-saying-kaddish

Comment: @GershonGold I actually saw that question and was wondering which bowings were being referred to there. I understood it was "Oseh Shalom..." - although I guess that's only 3 bowings? (I will edit my question to make it clearer). I was thinking about Danno's bowings - is there a source for that?

Comment: I also have seen on rare occasions bowing at yishtabach (the line right after the congregation says "y'he shma rabbah m'vorach ...).

Comment: @GershonGold Isn't that a duplicate?

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not asking, why, but where. All those answers go into why, appropriately. I don't even know what the source is to bow anytime before "Oseh Shalom"

Comment: I was looking for what Danno answered. Is there a source that says that we should do that?

Comment: I'm very confused if you are looking for sources that support a practice (as you have indicated in your last and third-to-last sentences) or if you are looking for descriptions of practices (as indicated in your fourth- and fifth-to-last sentences).

Comment: @DoubleAA: It did not seem like a duplicate to me. It seemed to be asking when, not why.

Comment: Well now one person thinks it's asking when, one thinks it's asking where, and one thinks it's asking based on what. I'm confused.

Comment: @DoubleAA Well, to clarify then I want to know if and where - meaning when saying which words, which is "when". Feel free to edit my question to make it clearer. Not sure how to improve on "At the beginning of Kaddish should he bow as well? And if so, when?"

Comment: @DoubleAA I found the answer to my question. There is a machlokess Shulchan Aruch 56:4 and Gra there if one should bow at Yisbarach, Yehei Shmei Raba, Yishtabach, Brich Hu, and Amein. I would add this as an answer if the question wasn't closed.