# Choreography of Kaddish

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, kaddish, bowing-kneeling

I have seen a number of different customs of when people bow or sway or bob or whatnot during Kaddish. Some of the people I have witnessed have been very knowledgeable, and I assume they weren't just falsely copying what they saw someone else do.

What are the various minhagim and where do they come from?  Does it differ for different kaddishes (e.g. mourners vs. chazzan's or half vs. full)?

Comment: Do you mean actual bows? Or just "shuckeling"?

Comment: @andrewmh20 actual full-fledged bows, sometimes even with a bending of the knees preceding it.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15739/759 Have you seen more than the two customs: bow at 4/5 specific places, and: don't bow at all?

Comment: @DoubleAA by specific you mean the same 4 places for all people?  Yes, I have seen people bowing at different places than other people bow.  Like I said in the question.

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16091&st=&pgnum=1129&hilite= Doesn't address but one custom without the source, so I'm not making it an answer.

Comment: Actually Gershon Gold's answer has a [link](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8837&st=&pgnum=225) to the full answer to your question.

Comment: The Bes Yosef on kaddish has all the rules. No time to review that now.